# SSH over VPN works only when both computers are connected to the same VPN server. Why?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vpn, internet

I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate question.
I have a PC running Lubuntu 18. It is connected to the Internet through VPN.

1. When the PC is not connected to the VPN I can SSH from anywhere;
2. When the PC is connected to the VPN I can only connect with SSH when the client PC is connected to the same VPN server as the Server PC;
3. I can connect via SSH through the local network at anytime - with or without VPN - that's how I manage the PC without a monitor.

I am trying to understand the reason for this. Is it because the VPN takes over the connection and when both computers are connected to the same VPN server both PCs are in the "same" network?
My provider uses double NAT. I do have a Static public IP. However, my router is not connected to the Internet directly - it has the ISP's IP. Somehow, the IPS has forwarded the Public IP to my router.
In addition I am able to log-in to remote management on my router using the public IP, although I get this notice - I guess because the IP of the router is not the public IP; remote management is off for security purposes. I only opened it to test the IP -

Remote Management Router Warning
[image: Remote Management Router Warning]

Thanks!

Comment: Look up "policy routing" as a way to fix this. (I corrected my post.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, your OS doesn't do source-based routing (or alternative features which would help with multihoming). So all outgoing packets, regardless of the connection they're associated with, follow the same routes and go out through the same interface.

As a result: When the PC is connected to a VPN which provides a new default route, and you try to make an SSH connection through the regular LAN, the PC tries to send the reply packets through the VPN – where they likely get discarded by anti-spoofing protection.

---

Possible workarounds (all of which involve manual configuration):

- Linux supports source-based routing for IPv6, using routes which additionally match the "from" address (RTA_SRC). For example, if you were to manually add the default route for your VPN, you could use:

  ```
  ip -6 route add ::/0 from fd01:2345:6789::/48 via fe80::1 dev tap0
  ```
- Linux supports policy-based routing for all IP versions using multiple routing tables:

  ```
  ip -6 route add ::/0 via fe80::1 dev tap0 table 1234
  ip -6 rule add pref 500 from fd01:2345:6789::/48 lookup 1234
  ```

Comment: Thanks so much! I looked up the IP routing set-up, and it is fixed. Now I can log in from anywhere :)